# Fit a simple S-curve and find the midpoint in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve-fitting

Let's say I have S-curved shaped data like below :

[S-Curved data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgEMa.png)

I would like too find the simplest way to fit this kind of curves AND use this fit to find the midpoint (aka the point where y=0.5). The fact is that I don't know beforehand where the midpoint.

Thanks a lot for your answers,

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly a case of fitting a [logistic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) with `L=1`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

data = np.loadtxt(r"\data.txt", delimiter=",")

x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]


def f(x: np.ndarray, k: float, x0: float):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-k*(x - x0)))


popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y, p0 = [1, 120])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5.6))

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, f(x, *popt), color="red")
plt.show()
```

`x0` is given by `popt[1]`, i.e. `121.18`.

[image]

Comment: That works very well, thank you so much!

Comment: It appears that when the curve is steep, curve fit struggles to find a good fit to my data. Then I have to increase the "maxfev" parameter quite a lot but it is not viable since I have a lot of data (and it still doesn't fit fit sometimes). Do you have a recommendation ?

Comment: Also, how can I include standard deviation to the fit ?

Comment: Can you share the data regarding your worst case scenario, please? Thanks.